# Carousel - slider using HTML 5 ONLY

Tags: html, carousel

Does anyone know if it is possible to create a carousel or slideshow using HTML only? I know it can be done using CSS and JavaScript but can't use these as I'm limited by the constraints of system I am working in. I've had a look online but can't find anything. My goal is to set up an automatically moving carousel of 3 different images.

Comment: ...and you can't use CSS or Javascript? How about SVG with SMIL?

Comment: I don't think you can achieve that with ordinary HTML. At least you'll need some CSS or JavaScript. Depends on your choice.

Comment: Hi Chris - unfortunately not...don't think possible but thought i'd give it a shot on here